# Failed to send email in wordpress custom plugin with SMTP plugin configured

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I have configured the SMTP and its sending email properly. I have to build a custom plugin that actually sends email notification on the certain event triggers. I am using the WP Mail SMTP plugin. I don't want to configure anything in my plugin. I just only want to extend their functionality and send emails. But I am failing to do that. I have written something like this

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'renderHTML' );
function renderHTML(){
    $to = 'demo@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Test';
    $message = "Demo Message";
    $headers='';
    wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

Kindly help what should be the way out for this.

Comment: did you check your spam mails?

Comment: @miteshkalal yes I did unfortunately no luck

Comment: test mail works properly?

Comment: @miteshkalal yes test email works properly

Answer (score 1):

this is my working code

```
function sendEmail($name,$email,$message,$subject)
{
    global $signature;
    $message .= "<br>" . $signature; 
 
    $admin = get_option('admin_email');
    $to = $email;
    $headers = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
    $headers .= "From: . $admin . \r\n" ;
    $headers .= "Reply-To: . $admin . \r\n" ;
  

    $sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    if($sent)
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}
```

Comment: i am using wp mail SMTP plugin for my email. And the same code i am using that i mentioned in the above. Now i debug that and i get 
Invalid address:  (From): wordpress@localhost

Comment: i am using Easy WP SMTP plugin for smtp. i think you sholld try this may be it works for you.

Comment: Invalid address:  (From): wordpress@localhost
This shouldn't be the case as I am using wp mail smtp plugin so this error should not come. I think I am not being able to override or call the same function used to send email

Comment: add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'sendEmail' );
function sendEmail(){
    $to = 'developer@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Test';
    $message = "Demo Message";
    $headers = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
    $headers .= "From: noreply@demo.co \r\n" ;
    $headers .= "Reply-To: noreply@demo.co \r\n" ;
    $test = wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo "Gg";
    echo $test;
 
    die;
}

Comment: I am using the above code to trigger email and also i have configured the easy wp smtp. From there test email is working fine. But from my code its not working

Comment: what value return  from $test?

Comment: test return empty

Comment: then try to debug code liine by line. i am sure you can do it

Comment: I have fixed that. Thanks for your support. It was having the issue in the header and charset